# UIWebview Load URL in Simulator but NOT Load URL in Device

Tags: ios, iphone, http, url, uiwebview

I am using uiwebview. All URL working fine in simulator. But my problem is some URL working fine and some URL not working in Device.

My code is as below

```
 NSString url;
 NSString *trimmedString = [url stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                           [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
 NSString *newString = [[trimmedString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
 NSLog(@"%@",newString);
 NSUInteger count = 0, length = [newString length];
 NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, length);
 while(range.location != NSNotFound)
  {
     range = [newString rangeOfString:@"http" options:0 range:range];
     if(range.location != NSNotFound)
      {
         range = NSMakeRange(range.location + range.length, length - (range.location + range.length));
         count++;
      }
  }
 NSLog(@"%d",count);
 if (count==1)
 {
    myURL=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithString:newString]];
 }
 else if (count>1)
 {
    NSArray *ArrObj=[newString componentsSeparatedByString:@"http"];
    NSArray *final=[[ArrObj objectAtIndex:count] componentsSeparatedByString:@"//"];
    myURL=[NSURL URLWithString:[@"http://" stringByAppendingString:[final objectAtIndex:1]]];
 }
  NSURLRequest *request=[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:myURL];
  [self.webview loadRequest:request];
```

In my code what i am doing is first of all url is comes from json data so i removed white spaces and newline and store string in "newString" Then I have 2 types url 1)url with one http 2)url with two http(if two http then take url after last http tag).So first I will count http tag and according to it  store url in "myURL".Then pass myURL to NSURLRequest and loadRequest from webview.

But 
1."http://bleacherreport.com/articles/2475279-sprint-cup-chase-2015-nascar-standings-and-schedule-after-coca-cola-600"
This is url which not working on device even if i put static URL.But working on simulator.

1."http://www.foxsports.com/nascar/shake-and-bake/american-sniper-chris-kyle-widow-taya-dale-earnhardt-jr-coca-cola-600-charlotte-052515" 
This is url which are working on both simulator and Device.

Please help me.
Any suggestion is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Use stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding like this NSString *strFileURL = [strFileURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strFileURL]];

Comment: Thank u for your replay...Encoding url as u suggest but still its not working....

Comment: What error is getting for the URL? Did you try it with a different net connection/wifi? Both your device and mac using same internet connection?

Comment: Yes,mac and device using same internet connection.  There is no any error  but webview display blanck. even webview's  (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView method is called successfully.